# Magento 2: addAttributeToFilter not working when filtering by ID

Tags: magento2, product-collection, addattributetofilter

`Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The "id" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.`
Here is my code

```
...
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory, 
...

$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('id',array("in"=>$productIds));
```

Can everybody helps me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to filtering by product ID, then use `entity_id` as 'id' column does not exist in the OOTB Magento products table.